# performance testing for web services (Microsoft web application stress tool?)

Tags: automated-tests

We need to provide a solution to do performance testing for our Web Services residing in our development environment. We were planning to create the test scripts using the object model of Microsoft Web Application Stress Tool. I have researched and not been able to find any examples.

Can anyone, who may have perhaps used this same tool for a similar solution, to please provide any advise and/or examples? Also, please provide any suggestions if a different tool can provide a more convenient solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: do you have access to Visual Studio Team Edition for Testers?

Comment: I think not. I have access to Visual Studio Team  Edition for software developers

Answer (score 1):

So a year or two back I had the same problem and was able to apply my experience with the grinder to the problem:
http://grinder.sourceforge.net/

Others in my environment reported success using ACT:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Center_Test

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Webload.I used it and it was a great tool. The IDE it provides allows you to record your browser action. When doing the stress testing, Webload will draw a nice graph on the fly.

edit: here is the link to the webload site: http://www.webload.org/

Answer (score 0):

WAST is a very old tool.  You might have better luck checking out some of the better open source load/performance tools like:  OpenSTA, JMeter, Webload, Grinder, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use the new version of SOAPbox from Vordel. This tool is very simple to use but provide very interesting functionalities. 
You can find it here : http://www.vordel.com/products/soapbox/

Answer (score 0):

VSTT provides load test option for web services - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhiln/archive/2007/02/05/performance-testing-asp-net-web-services-using-vsts.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You may have to stress test IIS itself since it's webservice, just loop open 5000 request.

Comment: This doesn't exactly test concurrency problems.

Comment: concurrency has nothing to do with a webservice performance, that should be handled in your code logic.